# Updating app with new codebase results in blank screen

Tags: react-native, google-play, app-store, auto-update

recently I've rewritten native iOS and Android apps (Swift, Java) to React Native. On testing, everything works fine, but when the application has been published to Appstore and Play Store, many (if not all, only judging by the users that contacted me before rollbacking to previous version) users were on update greeted with black screen. Once removing the app and installing it again, everything worked fine.

I can't really pinpoint any reason why this would happen. Has anyone met with this problem before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to stored user data (user preferences).
It seems that you are depending/using the same old users' preferences keys/values which is tricky to pull off.

Comment: You'reright, I'm using stored data in first version, but not in the second version - technically I may edit the rollbacked version to not use them and then release the new one.

Comment: Please tell me if this fix your blank screen issue.